# How to properly setup main.js and layout.vue with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-6

Good day guys,

I am experimenting with rails 6(webpack) and vue js. However im finding it difficult to setup the "router-view" element inside my layout.vue component. Im not sure if it has to do with the turbolinks or if im doing something wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

So First up is **index.html.erb** which is just a index page with a webpacker pack tag to load main.js

```
 <%= javascript_pack_tag 'main' %>
 <div id='hello'>
 </div>
```

Next is main my **main.js**

```
import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import router from 'router'
import Layout from 'layout.vue'

Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    new Vue({
    router: router,
    render: h => h(Layout)
  }).$mount('#hello')
})
```

Next is my **router.js.**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'layout',
            component: Vue.component('Layout', require('layout.vue')),
            children: [
                { path: 'test', name: 'test', component: Vue.component('Test', require('app.vue')) }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

And finally is **layout.vue** whiich is where is blows up

```
<template>  
  <div id='app'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='wrapper'>
        <sidebar></sidebar>
        <router-view/>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script> 
import Sidebar from 'sidebar.vue'
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {  message: "Testing"  
    }
 },
  components: {Sidebar}
}
</script>
```

The error im getting is

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <router-view> - did you register the component correctly?
found in Layout> at app/javascript/layout.vue
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import the layout and others components before register it. Assuming the components vue files are at root level:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Layout from './layout.vue'
import Test from './test.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'layout',
            component: Layout,
            children: [
                { path: 'test', 
                  name: 'test', 
                  component: Test 
                 }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

Hope it suits you.

Comment: Hey man thanks for answering but i still get the same error after i've chnaged the router.js like you explained. What else could it be ?

Comment: Also man i have vue dev tools installed in chrome and when i click the Routing tab it displays "no router detected". If its my file structure it would have complained at the import statements. What am i missing :(